# Regular Expression (Captures to be used twice in a lookaround)

Tags: regex, capture-group

String is:

> test1, test2, test3

Output required:

```
[b]Example Output:[/b] [url=https://urlhere=test1]test1[/url], [url=https://urlhere=test2]test2[/url], [url=https://urlhere=test3]test3[/url]
```

Is it possible with regular expressions to use the same capture more than twice?

See where `test1, test2, test3` are all used twice with the `,\s` been removed from the string with the three separated into the output as shown.

I've heard about Atomic grouping which sounds like this could work but I'm not sure.

Any help would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question, but what about [`([^\s,]+)` replace with `[url=https://urlhere=$1]$1[/url]`](https://regex101.com/r/WHFifD/1). You just need to prepend `[b]Example Output:[/b]`

Comment: Sorry if my Q seemed to be a little confusing. But I'd say that this is answered by my first test of it. But having said that it doesn't work in Mp3tag. It says **invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator**. I forget what regexp language it uses.

Comment: You can use captured groups in your replacement an unlimited number of times

Comment: It's PERL reg exp. Problem is `([^\s,]+)` doesn't work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Got a working version for Mp3tag:
`$regexp('This Artist 1, This Artist 2, This Artist 3','\s*([^\,]+[^,\s])','[url="https://urlhere=$1"]$1[/url]')`